# Associate Ldap user to a group with Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm having problems to find how to associate a #Ldap user to a given group.

That is what I have tried:

```
    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes();

    BasicAttribute basicAttrs = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
    basicAttrs.add("top");
    basicAttrs.add("person");

    BasicAttribute memberOf = new BasicAttribute("memberOf");
    memberOf.add("Managers"); // Tried with distinguished name too
    memberOf.add("Administrators"); // Tried with distinguished name too

    attrs.put(basicAttrs);
    attrs.put("cn", user.getLogin());
    attrs.put("name", user.getLogin());
    attrs.put("login", user.getLogin());
    attrs.put("mail", user.getMail());
    attrs.put("displayName", user.getDisplayName());
    attrs.put("memberOf", memberOf);

    try {
        ctx.bind("CN=" + user.getLogin() + "," + baseDn, null, attrs);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also tried to use the distinguished names like: "CN=Managers,OU=<system_name>,OU=Users,OU=<server>,DC=com", but didn't work.
I think it should be somewhere to reference the Ldap group.

But I got this error:

```
javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: Malformed 'memberOf' attribute value; remaining name 'CN=lcarvalho,OU=<system_name>,OU=Users,OU=<server>,DC=com'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.encodeAttribute(LdapClient.java:951)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.add(LdapClient.java:999)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_bind(LdapCtx.java:396)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_bind(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:197)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.bind(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:186)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.bind(InitialDirContext.java:158)
...
```

This is all the stack trace besides my application lines.

Comment: I have not used JNDI to work with LDAP, but have you checked in your LDAP Server, if the 'person' object class has 'memberOf' attribute? What's the LDAP server you're developing against? In any case, you have to specify the full DN for the 'memberOf'.

Comment: I tried the same right now just for the sake of testing this and can reproduce the issue. 'memberOf' attribute does exist and DN is correct. But I think the main problem here is that adding a user to a group should happen from the group object, not the user object (as @EJP commented further below).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using OpenLDAP the `memberOf` attribute is maintained automatically by the `memberOf` overlay, and your application shouldn't write it at all. What you should be doing is adding the DN of the user to the `uniqueMember` or `roleOccupant` etc. attribute of the group he is joining. Then its DN will magically appear in his `memberOf` attribute.

Comment: This answer is correct and should be marked as that. It's confirmed as well by the answer for this very same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147625/java-ldap-add-group-to-user-issue-error-code-53-will-not-perform

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your DN is wrong, because it seems you've specified one extra Organizational Unit instead of Domain Component:

```
"CN=Managers,OU=<system_name>,OU=Users,OU=<server>,DC=com"
```

should be:

```
"cn=Managers,ou=<system_name>,ou=Users,dc=<server>,dc=com"
```

In LDAP the Directory Structure starts with 2 domain components, which are a reversed company domain name (by convention).

In order for your code to work, you have to take into account the following:

- there's a schema "Person" that's loaded in your LDAP Server
- there's an attribute "MemberOf" defined in your "Person" schema
- "MemberOf" requires full DN as entry

I would also encourage you to take a look at [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/index.html).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `memberOf` attribute is wrong. The `memberOf` attribute is probably a distinguished name. LDAP clients should consult the schema (the base DN of which might be available in the [root DSE](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/)) when in doubt about the syntax, ordering, or matching rules of an attribute.

Comment: Thank you but I also tried to use distinguished names, I omitted the baseDn, but here it is:

`String baseDn = "OU=Delphos,OU=Users,OU=Nextel,DC=tades,DC=com,DC=br"`;

And here it is the both distinguished names I'm using:

`memberOf.add("CN=Gestores,OU=Delphos,OU=Roles,OU=Nextel,DC=tades,DC=com,DC=br");
memberOf.add("CN=Administradores,OU=Delphos,OU=Roles,OU=Nextel,DC=tades,DC=com,DC=br");`

I have the schemas Roles and Users created in Ldap server. I have also the attribute "memberOf" created, when I try to omit it the error changes to `Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v1db1`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Check the value type of this attribute using any client of ldap (for example: Apache Directory Studio). If you try to replace attribute which type is String with int value it will thrown this error.

Comment: What `int` value? No such thing mentioned in the OP.