# Java LDAP - Add group to user issue - Error code 53 - WILL_NOT_PERFORM

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to add an user into Active Directory.
Having in mind:

- Using SSL
- Certificate ok
- Password works fine

With out group association, the user is correctly created.

When I try to associate the user to a group I get the following error:
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A1021, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

I have used the DN and NAME group attributes but none worked. 
My code is:

```
    ctx = getContext();
    ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN,entry); // it works fine

    Attribute memberOf1 = new BasicAttribute("memberOf","NAME_OF_THE_GROUP");
    Attributes atts     = new BasicAttributes();
    atts.put(memberOf1);
    ctx.modifyAttributes(entryDN, LdapContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, atts); // ## it doesn't work
```

I tried LdapContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE and  LdapContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE.
Also, I tried to add the group with the other attributes but all situation gave me the same error.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Cheers!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

memberOf is a constructed attribute.  You have to add the user to the group's member property, not add the group to the user's memberOf property.

Comment: Lovely, it solved my problem!I will post the solution in couple minutes.

Comment: BasicAttribute member = new BasicAttribute("member",entryDN);
    Attributes atts = new BasicAttributes();
    atts.put(member);
    ctx.modifyAttributes("GROUP_DN", LdapContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, atts);

Answer (score 7):

The solution code is:

```
BasicAttribute member = new BasicAttribute("member",entryDN);
Attributes atts = new BasicAttributes();
atts.put(member);
ctx.modifyAttributes("GROUP_DN", LdapContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, atts);
```

Thanks Hall72215.

Comment: Even shorter:  Attributes member = new BasicAttributes("member", entryDN);

ctx.modifyAttributes("GROUP_DN", LdapContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, member);

Comment: You should update your initial question with the final solution so it doesn't get lost in the answers but thanks for posting!

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this, it works for me

```
ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
String userDn="cn=user name,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
String groupDn="cn=Group Name,CN=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
Attribute mod =new BasicAttribute("member",userDn);
mods[0] =new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, mod);
ldapContext.modifyAttributes(groupDn, mods);
```

Comment: thanks i got solution for using this code

Comment: I also got the solution using your block of code :) thanks