# Add a user to multiple AD groups using Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

A very similar problem to [Associate Ldap user to a group with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329229/associate-ldap-user-to-a-group-with-java/67658781?noredirect=1#comment119589656_67658781) but instead of adding 1 user to 1 AD group, I'm trying to find a way to add 1 user to multiple AD groups using Java.

Comment: Can you please include the code you have already tried and the errors/undesirable conditions you encountered? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [Associate Ldap user to a group with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329229/associate-ldap-user-to-a-group-with-java/67658781?noredirect=1#comment119589656_67658781) worked. I just had to loop and add the same user to multiple AD groups.
The issue was when I tried to retrieve "memberOf" I was casting the field output to string directly so it only displayed the first value. Once I looped through "memberOf", I got all the AD groups in the output.